# «Крым как он есть». Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Крым как он есть. Стоит ли употребить какие-либо знаки препинания?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Крым как он есть.**

***Как он есть*** ― это  значит реально, объективно, без прикрас.

Оборот в этом предложении является именным сказуемым, запятая не ставится.

В других случаях  оборот может обособляться или не обособляться  по обычным правилам.

**Примеры:**

1) ― Ну, есть **человек как он есть,** и есть человек как идеальное представление о самом себе. [Алексей Слаповский. Синдром Феникса // «Знамя», 2006]

Мир без войны пригляден **как он есть.** [Виктор Астафьев. Последний поклон (1968-1991)]

2) Никому не интересен ребенок **сам по себе, как он есть**. [Ирина Прусс. Прекрасные дамы — мамы // «Знание - сила», 2010]

Он воспринимает мир **таким, как он есть,** во всех его проявлениях... [Максим Кастет.  2004.06.10]